# Doesn't use GROUP BY oracle in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, group-by

I have a example: I am using C# to solve Oracle database problem

```
    cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select DATE_START from EMPLOYEE;";
```

It works successfull.
BUt when I use GROUP BY, it doesm't work.

```
        cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select DATE_START from EMPLOYEE GROUP BY DATE_START;";
```

It doesn't work

```
ORA-00911: invalid character.
```

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the semicolon(`;`) from `CommandText` like

```
cmd.CommandText = "select DATE_START from EMPLOYEE GROUP BY DATE_START"; 
                                                                   //^^ From Here
```

I am not sure why it should be a problem, but I have seen similar issue before with Oracle + ADO.Net.

Also, **if you are not using any aggregate methods then you can use `DISTINCT`** keyword instead of `GROUP BY` like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_START from EMPLOYEE";
```

Comment: Thank you so much... It worked but I don't know why it works...
I use GROUP BY keyword to  calculate sum of salary for each employe..
Thanks